# I have two different listview activities

Tags: java, android

I have two different listview activities. I want when i click on a list item in activity 1 this data gets transfer to activity 2 & when i click on a list item in activity 2 this data also gets transfer to activity 3. How can i do this programmatically?

Answer (score 0):

In your adapter, either create a view where you want the click action and then add the click-listener like:

```
holder.yourView.setOnClickListener {
    interface.passDataAndLaunchActivity(data)
}
```

Where the interface will be your view which you can initialize from your activity when you initialize your adapter. In the interface, you can have the method which launches another `activity` and you can pass the data to it. You can override that method in your activity to launch another `activity` and pass the data with `putExtra` to any other activities.

If you want to click the list item you can directly use the click listener on the view holder.

This will do it.